# Import package error on Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, package, jupyter-notebook

So i installed a ML package called indicoio through pip. I am able to import this package on sublime text, and the terminal(OSX) runs it correcty. It works perfectly here.

However, when I import this package on Jupyter Notebook (on safari), it gives a Module Not Found Error.

What could be the problem here? Could it have something to do with the working directory of Jupyter Notebooks and where the package is installed?

Thank you. The code is shown below.

```
import indicoio
indicoio.config.api_key = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
```

Comment: jupyter does not use the python installation than my regular python version (at least on my windows version), and I have to install the packages via conda : https://conda.io/docs/user-guide/tasks/manage-pkgs.html

Comment: Check out this post for tips on solving import issues: http://takluyver.github.io/posts/i-cant-import-it.html